# Manage VPS server and install cpanel alternative

Tags: server, vps, centos6

Hello all i just bought my first VPS server from hostinger and i dont know how to use it as earlier i used to use only shared hostings so i used to get my cpanel for the site where all the services are listed but this is not the case in VPS and Dedicated so i just wanted your advice and if possible a detailed step wise instructions on how to manage and install free cpanel alternatives on my VPS server

Things that i have IP address SSH and other things that is in VPS

what i need is just to install some softwares free on my server to create accounts and host websites. i need ftp, php myadmin, emails, cron jobs etc....

My srver details are CENTOS 6.7 x86_64 virtuozzo

Comment: will you able to host your VPS server. What steps you followed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try open source control panels like CentOS Web Panel,  ZPanel, WebMin, ISPConfig, etc. I personally use CentOS web Panel as open source alternative of cPanel. Here's the guide you can follow to install Centos Web Panel.

http://centos-webpanel.com/installation-instructions

Answer (score 1):

There are many free available Control panel for Linux Like ISPConfig or spacewalk.

You can download them from their website and installation instruction are also provided on their website.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to go with Kloxo hosting control panel. It is free open source control panel. It has many features like manage billing, hosting, backup etc.. You can find complete features list and information from [here..](http://lxcenter.org/software/kloxo)

It is also compatible with your Operating System. You can find installation guide for this hosting control panel from [here..](http://www.tecmint.com/install-kloxo-web-hosting-control-panel-in-centos/)

[Administrator Guide](http://oldwiki.lxcenter.org/Kloxo+Admin+Guide)
[User Guide](http://oldwiki.lxcenter.org/Kloxo+User+Guide)

Hope, this will help and cover all your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install some free server configuration panel.
You can try a good known [WebMin](http://webmin.com) or relatively new and advanced [ServerSuit](http://serversuit.com).

Then you can install all the software you need to including the LAMP stack, mail servers, FTP servers and manage all those things from your browser of course.

ServerSuit also supports mobile devices which I prefer personally.